# Op-amp output voltage equation

Tags: operational-amplifier, electrical

Never seen this kind of op amp. How do I solve for voltage output?

[image]

Comment: How different is it to an inverting amplifier? What's the output impedance of the opamp?

Comment: I think it's an inverting op-amp with an additional voltage source through R3. As for R1, there isn't one. After Ri and Rfb, the numbers just skip to R2.

Comment: R3 has no impact on Vo. The only exception is if the op amp is an open-collector output.  Then V12 sets an upper limit on how high the output can go.

Comment: I'll want to answer it few hours later.. Is there any way to mark questions for answering later?

Comment: Assume the Op-amp inputs take no current and the Op-amp tries to keep its inputs the same as each other.  Show us your efforts and we will help if you get stuck.  But, we want to see your attempts first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit (assuming an ideal opamp):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5na3Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
0=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_4
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, when we have an ideal opamp we know that \$\text{V}_\text{k}:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=\text{V}_2\$. So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{k}}{\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_\text{k}}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
0=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_\text{k}}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_\text{k}}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_\text{k}}{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, for the output voltage we get:

$$\text{V}_3=-\frac{\text{R}_3}{\text{R}_2}\cdot\text{V}_\text{y}\tag{5}$$

Comment: Ideally the resistors in your solution should match the names shown in the question, which they do not.

Answer (score 0):

Use superposition. With VI2 set to 0, the circuit is just a standard inverting amplifier. With VI1 set to 0, the virtual ground at the op-amp's inverting input prevents current through the feedback network so the output gets pulled down to ground.

Comment: Would that just make the output dependent on VI1?

Comment: Yes, the virtual ground at the op-amp's inverting terminal ensures that Vo is only dependent on VI1.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this pretty basically with the fundamental rules of the ideal opamp.

Now, since nobody would draw a schematic incorporating an ideal opamp and include multiple components that make no difference for that, unless this is a homework exercise,  and then you've been given enough hints ;), we must assume this is a real-world Opamp. It would be wise to find out which actual Opamp that is, and get its datasheet.

R2 would probably be relatively large, and only serve to limit bias current between ground and non-inverting input.

R3 is a bit of a power move: Depending on whether it's a weak or strong resistor, it's more of a base load (maybe to keep a dynamic system stable?), or something that strongly pulls the opamp output towards Vi2; it's unusual that you'd load the opamp, but quite possibly this is from an application where this was an easy way to get somewhat of a saturating I/O curve. Maybe a softclip for an old audio thing?

Or maybe Vi2 is actually fed by a high-impedance voltage source itself, and thus something like a signal output? That'd be very much in the vacuum tube kind of thinking for several types of amplifiers, but that would date this schematic to the *very* early days of opamps...

Comment: For op-amps with bias current, you size R2 equal to the parallel combination of Ri and Rfb, and it removes the output bias due to bias current (but not the bias due to bias current *bias*).  R3 may also be there to pull the output all the way to the supply voltage -- this is a nice trick with the LM358 or other early "single-supply" amps that would pull their output nearly to ground, but only up to 2V less than supply -- R3 would finish *that* job, and you'd get nearly rail-rail output, at the cost of some standing current in R3.